# staticmethod, class method, nested method

Tags: python, static-methods, nested-function

I have the need to validate some data. Sometimes, the data is repeated in my data structure, sometimes it is singular. When it is multiple, I have a flag set for this. In order to reduce code, I am attempting to do the following psuedocode:

```
def validate(self):
    if self.multiple
        for chunk in self.data: #not real code here
            validate_one_chunk(chunk)
    else:
        validate_one_chunk(self.data)
```

My question is the following:
validate is a method in a class. validate_one_chunk does not read or modify anything in the class. If the validation fails, it raises an exception, otherwise it does nothing except validate.

Should validate_one_chunk be:

'regular' method in the class

static method in the class

nested inside of validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 'regular' method in the class

No.

> static method in the class

No.

> nested inside of validate

Maybe. If other classes need it then make it a module-level function instead.

Comment: If I make it a nested function, then I cannot directly test the behavior of the nested function, correct? Then I should just test the outer function so that all the code paths in the inner function are exercised?

Comment: Also, can you please explain (1 or 2 lines) why not the first two?

Comment: Your question already covers that. The function has nothing to do with the class.